# How to save file to temp location? Cocoa/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

My idea is to open a file dialog box using:

```
NSOpenPanel* openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
NSArray* imageTypes = [NSImage imageTypes];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[openPanel setResolvesAliases:YES];
[openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:imageTypes];
[openPanel setPrompt:@"Upload"];
[openPanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory()]];
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    [openPanel close];
```

Then to be able to save the selected file in the temporary location under a different name generated by my random name method:

```
NSString* myString = [self randomStringWithLength:7];
```

I will then FTP the temp file and delete it afterwards.

Anyone know how I could do this? Example code?

Comment: What stops you from using your sandbox folder?

Answer (score 3):

You can checkout `NSFileManager`, it has a method called: `copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:` and to get the temp folder you can use `NSTemporaryDirectory()`